# How to stop GDB from initialising memory

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I have an embedded GUI application that I am debugging in eclipse. However, when I launch the debug, GDB spends 90 seconds writing zero's to all of the GUI memory.

Is there a way to tell it to not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It was to add (NOLOAD) to the section holding the RAM data in the eclipse linker file

```
.GUI_RAM (NOLOAD) : 
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.GUI_RAM)
    . = ALIGN(4);
} >MEMORY_B1
```

The GUI memory is placed in this section like this

```
uint32_t _aMemory[GUI_NUMBYTES / 4] __attribute__ ((section(".GUI_RAM")));
```

Answer (score 0):

> GDB spends 90 seconds writing zero's to all of the GUI memory.

You are mistaken, GDB *does no such thing* (at least not by default).

Comment: OK, so its eclipse telling GDB to zero the memory. Still need to find a way to stop it happening. GDB log shows it spending minutes writing zeros to the 32MB of external SDRAM. This is what I need to stop.

Comment: @user812624 Your question lacks *all* necessary details. You are unlikely to get a satisfactory answer until you edit it to supply details about your setup, what exactly you found in the GDB log, etc.

Comment: what chip are you using?  are you using openOCD?  JTAG? SWD?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume OpenOCD, and that you are using a manufacturer provided IDE, they do stuff like this, you need to address your question to their support.